# Jcombobox with jtable issue for rows

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jtable

When I select first (combobox) column of first row, and again select  second (combobox) column of second row, same value comes in second combo box. I tried with many ways, but did not found any solution.

// column11.setCellRenderer(new MyComboBoxRenderer(str));
           // column11.setCellEditor(new MyComboBoxEditor(str));

```
        //column.setCellEditor(new ComboBoxCellEditor(comboBox2));
      //  comboBox2.setSelectedItem("s");
        //column11.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox2));

        //Set up tool tips for the sport cells.
       // DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer =
        //        new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
      //  renderer.setToolTipText("Click for combo box");

       // EachRowEditor11 rowEditor2 = new EachRowEditor11(tableMappingSheet);
      //  rowEditor2.setEditorAt(3, new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox2));
      //  rowEditor2.setEditorAt(4, new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox2));
     //   rowEditor2.setEditorAt(5, new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox2));
      //  tableMappingSheet.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellEditor(rowEditor2);
      //  column11.setCellRenderer(renderer);
        /*MyCellRenderer test  = new MyCellRenderer();
        DefaultCellEditor defaultCellEditor=new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox2);
        JList jlist  = new JList(lst.toArray());
        column11.setCellEditor((TableCellEditor) test.getListCellRendererComponent(jlist, null, -1, true, true));
        */
        //lst.
       // column11.setCellRenderer(lst);

       // column11.setCellRenderer()
        Java2sAutoComboBox comboBox = new Java2sAutoComboBox(lst);
        comboBox.setDataList(lst);
        column11.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
       // tableMappingSheet.repaint();


        TableColumn columnForLookupValidation = tableMappingSheet.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
         columnForLookupValidation.setCellEditor(new ComboBoxCellEditor(comboBoxForLookupValidation));
         //table.getColumnModel().addColumnModelListener(columnModelListener);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).  Note that given there are only 5 code lines in that mess above, it is more 'noise' than 'information'.

Comment: *"Please help.. It is urgent.."*  So hire someone, urgently.  But don't mention your poor time management to people who are offering help for free.

Comment: This has been abandoned without improvement, so suggest it is closed as unclear.